# Share directory config accross apache vhosts

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have several vhosts setup in apache (CentOS), in a external file conf.d/vhost.conf

They all have a config like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/app/example_site/public"            
    <Directory "/app/example_site/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In the e.g. 20 virtualhosts defined in this conf file, and the part between `<Directory "xxxx"> </Directory>` is the same for each vhost. It should be possible to use a default directory config for each vhost right? I can't find/figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just dump the common info into a file and use the [`Include` directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/core.html#include) to load it:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/app/example_site/public"            
    <Directory "/app/example_site/public">
        Include "/path/to/common_dir_config.conf"
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```